# Executing cat ./file1.txt file2.txt >> merged.txt fails with java.lang.RuntimeException: cat: >: No such file or directory

Tags: java

I'm trying to execute this Linux command from Java: `cat ./file1.txt ./file2.txt >> ./merged.txt`

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat", "FULLPATH/file1.txt", "FULLPATH/file2.txt", ">>", "FULLPATH/merged.txt");
```

This works directly in the console but fails in Java:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: cat: >: No such file or directory
cat: FULLPATH/merged.txt: No such file or directory
```

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Alternatively, since the point of Java is X-platform operation, do the ```cat```  in pure Java. ```SequenceInputStream``` is your friend ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirection `>>` is a feature of your shell so you need to run under that shell. Java process launch cannot handle. Try calling your shell to handle the command such as say:

```
String []cmd = new String[] {"/bin/bash", "-c", "cat ... >> xyz.txt"};
```

Alternatively use `ProcessBuilder` with file [redirectOutput](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput(java.io.File)) for saving standard output to a file and drop the ">>" part, and you may need to use full pathname to the `cat` executable if that is not on the PATH of JVM.

```
String []cmd = new String[] {"cat", "path1", "path2"};
```